# I'm having trouble adding a VPN. It won't save the settings. 20.04

Tags: networking, vpn

20.04, So here is the process that I'm using to add the VPN.

[OpenVPN setup in Ubuntu 19.10 – IPVanish](https://support.ipvanish.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038825793-OpenVPN-setup-in-Ubuntu-19-10?_ga=2.188460384.910127319.1595541307-654961739.1595541307&_gac=1.142207366.1595541309.EAIaIQobChMI3M6jw67k6gIVLwiICR1rLQ7cEAAYASAAEgIt_vD_BwE)

After entering all the info step by step exactly how it states in the instructions, I click the add button and it takes me back the previous screen and the VPN isn't added... it looks as if I never even tried to add a vpn. I get a gray box that says "Not set up". Anyone have this issue? Do I need to install something to be able to use VPN's? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I think you might need to install either the package `network-manager-openvpn` or `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` for this to work. Also make sure you have package `openvpn` installed.

Comment: They were already installed. Thanks though.